# Understanding the processing pipeline

Tags: c#, linq

Take

```
        var query = Process.GetProcesses()
                            .OrderBy(p => p.WorkingSet64)
                            .ThenByDescending(p => p.Threads.Count);
                            .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 9);
```

It works fine.  Take

```
        var query = Process.GetProcesses()
                            .OrderBy(p => p.WorkingSet64)
                            .ThenByDescending(p => p.Threads.Count);
                            //.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 9);

        query = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 9);
```

This does not work.  I do not understand why the first method works.  In my mind these queries are the same.  ThenByDescending returns `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` which is piped into Where().  The first method should not work because Where only works with `IEnumerable<T>`.  Alas...it does work.

How does this processing pipeline function?

Comment: Array implements `IEnumerable` and `GetProcesses` returns an array of processes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is because of a misunderstanding of the `var` keyword and LINQ queries.

[var (C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

Using the `var` keyword is the same as specifying the same type as the right side of the assignment. It does not mean that you can assign any type to the variable.

In LINQ queries, most of the basic expressions return an `IEnumerable`, but it many cases, they do not return just an `IEnumerable`. Instead, they return an type that inherits from `IEnumerable`.

In this case, you are doing the equivalent of this:

```
IEnumerable<Process> query = Process.GetProcesses()
                            .OrderBy(p => p.WorkingSet64)
                            .ThenByDescending(p => p.Threads.Count);
                            .Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 9);
```

and

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Process> query = Process.GetProcesses()
                                    .OrderBy(p => p.WorkingSet64)
                                    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Threads.Count);

// Won't work because Where doesn't return an IOrderedEnumerable.
query = query.Where(p => p.ProcessName.Length < 9);
```

The reason that the first snippet works is because `IOrderedEnumerable` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so you can use it as such.

To fix the problem in the second example, you need to explicitly declare `query` as `IEnumerable<Process>`.